# OpenCV setup - "plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found"

Tags: android, gradle

I'm pretty new to Android development (and gradle). I'm trying to set up the openCV sdk within a new project. The code in the Application/build.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

The opencv/build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

And the settings.gradle is:

```
include 'Application'
include ':opencv'
```

I get the error in the title when I try to sync the project. Any explanation or help is appreciated. I've looked at a few other similar threads and tried some suggestions in them but nothings worked so far. Thanks!